# why does this Java method leak—and why does inlining it fix the leak?

Tags: java, memory-management, clojure, garbage-collection, sequence

I wrote a minimal somewhat-lazy (`int`) sequence class, [GarbageTest.java](https://github.com/Bill/java-garbage-test/blob/master/src/test/java/GarbageTest.java), as an experiment, to see if I could process very long, lazy sequences in Java, the way I can in Clojure.

Given a `naturals()` method that returns the lazy, infinite, sequence of natural numbers; a `drop(n,sequence)` method that drops the first `n` elements of `sequence` and returns the rest of the `sequence`; and an `nth(n,sequence)` method that returns simply: `drop(n, lazySeq).head()`, I wrote two tests:

```
static int N = (int)1e6;

// succeeds @ N = (int)1e8 with java -Xmx10m
@Test
public void dropTest() {
    assertThat( drop(N, naturals()).head(), is(N+1));
}

// fails with OutOfMemoryError @ N = (int)1e6 with java -Xmx10m
@Test
public void nthTest() {
    assertThat( nth(N, naturals()), is(N+1));
}
```

Note that the body of `dropTest()` was generated by copying the body of `nthTest()` and then invoking IntelliJ's "inline" refactoring on the `nth(N, naturals())` call. So it seems to me that the behavior of `dropTest()` should be identical to the behavior of `nthTest()`.

But it isn't identical! `dropTest()` runs to completion with N up to 1e8 whereas `nthTest()` fails with `OutOfMemoryError` for N as small as 1e6.

I've avoided inner classes. And I've experimented with a variant of my code, [ClearingArgsGarbageTest.java](https://github.com/Bill/java-garbage-test/blob/master/src/test/java/ClearingArgsGarbageTest.java), that nulls method parameters before calling other methods. I've applied the YourKit profiler. I've looked at the byte code. I just cannot find the leak that causes `nthTest()` to fail.

Where's the "leak"? And why does `nthTest()` have the leak while `dropTest()` does not?

Here's the rest of the code from [GarbageTest.java](https://github.com/Bill/java-garbage-test/blob/master/src/test/java/GarbageTest.java) in case you don't want to click through to the Github project:

```
/**
 * a not-perfectly-lazy lazy sequence of ints. see LazierGarbageTest for a lazier one
 */
static class LazyishSeq {
    final int head;

    volatile Supplier<LazyishSeq> tailThunk;
    LazyishSeq tailValue;

    LazyishSeq(final int head, final Supplier<LazyishSeq> tailThunk) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tailThunk = tailThunk;
        tailValue = null;
    }

    int head() {
        return head;
    }

    LazyishSeq tail() {
        if (null != tailThunk)
            synchronized(this) {
                if (null != tailThunk) {
                    tailValue = tailThunk.get();
                    tailThunk = null;
                }
            }
        return tailValue;
    }
}

static class Incrementing implements Supplier<LazyishSeq> {
    final int seed;
    private Incrementing(final int seed) { this.seed = seed;}

    public static LazyishSeq createSequence(final int n) {
        return new LazyishSeq( n, new Incrementing(n+1));
    }

    @Override
    public LazyishSeq get() {
        return createSequence(seed);
    }
}

static LazyishSeq naturals() {
    return Incrementing.createSequence(1);
}

static LazyishSeq drop(
        final int n,
        final LazyishSeq lazySeqArg) {
    LazyishSeq lazySeq = lazySeqArg;
    for( int i = n; i > 0 && null != lazySeq; i -= 1) {
        lazySeq = lazySeq.tail();
    }
    return lazySeq;
}

static int nth(final int n, final LazyishSeq lazySeq) {
    return drop(n, lazySeq).head();
}
```

Comment: If you're working in Java, wouldn't it be more natural to use Streams?

Comment: @AlanThompson in general you are right. Streams are the "Java way". I'm doing this as an experiment into doing things the Haskell/Clojure way: immutable, lazy, scalable sequences. See this for more: https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/issues/2245#issuecomment-390437457

Comment: Experiments are often helpful, but you don't want to spend too much time "reinventing the wheel". If you haven't looked yet, you probably should review the Clojure LazySeq source code:  https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/e5fc803ff13f783661ef9491842719ab68a245ca/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java

Comment: The only purpose of my experiment was to see if it was possible to implement Clojure-style immutable, lazy, scalable sequences as a Java _library_. My conclusion is that it is not possible, and that Java libraries like http://www.vavr.io/ will not be able to do it.

I believe that if I took the Clojure sequence implementation classes and called into them from my own Java code, that code would exhibit the same memory consumption as my example—unless I gave the `-Xcomp` option to the JVM.

Comment: You could absolutely call into the Clojure classes without leaking memory without setting any JVM options – might just need to "clear locals" the way Clojure does. Added an answer to explain how that's done in the Java portion of the Clojure runtime.

Comment: (Of course that it could technically be done doesn't mean it'd feel anywhere near as natural as using Clojure classes in Clojure, with locals clearing handled by the compiler behind the scenes.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your method

```
static int nth(final int n, final LazyishSeq lazySeq) {
    return drop(n, lazySeq).head();
}
```

the parameter variable `lazySeq` hold a reference to the first element of your sequence during the entire `drop` operation. This prevents the entire sequence from getting garbage collected.

In contrast, with

```
public void dropTest() {
    assertThat( drop(N, naturals()).head(), is(N+1));
}
```

the first element of your sequence is returned by `naturals()` and directly passed to the invocation of `drop`, thus removed from the operand stack and does not exist during the execution of `drop`.

Your attempt to set the parameter variable to `null`, i.e.

```
static int nth(final int n, /*final*/ LazyishSeq lazySeqArg) {
    final LazyishSeq lazySeqLocal = lazySeqArg;
    lazySeqArg = null;
    return drop(n,lazySeqLocal).head();
}
```

does not help, as now, the `lazySeqArg` variable is `null`, but the `lazySeqLocal` holds a reference to the first element.

A local variable does not prevent garbage collection in general, the collection of otherwise unused objects is *permitted*, but that doesn’t imply that a particular implementation is capable of doing it.

In case of the HotSpot JVM, only optimized code will get rid of such unused references. But here, `nth` is not a hot spot, as the heavy things happen within `drop` method.

This is the reason why the same issue does not appear at the `drop` method, despite it also holds a reference to the first element in its parameter variable. The `drop` method contains the loop doing the actual work, hence, is very likely to get optimized by the JVM, which may cause it to eliminate unused variables, allowing the already processed part of the sequence to become collected.

There are many factors which may affect the JVM’s optimizations. Besides the different shape of the code, it seems that that rapid memory allocations during the unoptimized phase may also reduce the optimizer’s improvements. Indeed, when I run with `-Xcompile`, to forbid interpreted execution altogether, both variants run successfully, even `int N = (int)1e9` is no problem anymore. Of course, forcing compilation raises the startup time.

I have to admit that I do not understand why the mixed mode performs *that* much worse and I’ll investigate further. But generally, you have to be aware that the efficiency of the garbage collector is implementation dependent, so objects collected in one environment may stay in memory in another.

Comment: Brilliant. How then, is the Clojure compiler, able to avoid this sort of problem? Does it always forbid interpreted execution? Where did you even find `-Xcompile` documented? I'm finding it difficult to Google that.

Comment: Ah, I think I see it documented here for e.g. macOS, as `-Xcomp`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

Comment: @BillBurcham Clojure explicitly clears references that could be problematic in this way. I've added an answer to explain how.

Comment: @BillBurcham (Perhaps I should mention here that the way this clearing is accomplished is different to the attempt to set the parameter to `null` which then introduces a new local that holds on to the head. Clojure clears *all* local references possessed by the caller before handing off control. The shortest summary is that it uses a helper method so that it has the opportunity to pass the equivalent of `lazySeq = null` – an assignment expression setting `lazySeq` to `null` – as an extra argument in calls such as the call to `drop` inside `nth` just for the local-clearing side effect.)

Comment: @BillBurcham yes, `-Xcompile` seems to be an alias for `-Xcomp`. I used it from my memory (it’s an ancient option and rarely needed) and since it worked, I didn’t compare with the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Clojure implements a strategy for dealing with this sort of scenario which it calls "locals clearing". There's support for it in the compiler that makes it kick in automatically where required in pure Clojure code (unless disabled at compilation time – this is sometimes useful for debugging). Clojure does also clear locals in various places in its Java runtime, however, and the way it does that could be used in Java libraries and possibly even application code, though it would undoubtedly be somewhat cumbersome.

Before I get into what Clojure does, here's a short summary of what is going on in this example:

1. `nth(int, LazyishSeq)` is implemented in terms of `drop(int, LazyishSeq)` and `LazyishSeq.head()`.
2. `nth` passes both its arguments to `drop` and has no further use for them.
3. `drop` can easily be implemented so as to avoid holding on to the head of the passed-in sequence.

Here `nth` still holds on to the head of its sequence argument. The runtime may potentially discard that reference, but it is not guaranteed that it will.

The way Clojure deals with this is by clearing the reference to the sequence explicitly before control is handed off to `drop`. This is done using a rather elegant trick ([link to the below snippet on GitHub as of Clojure 1.9.0](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Util.java#L197)):

```
//  clojure/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Util.java

/**
 *   Copyright (c) Rich Hickey. All rights reserved.
 *   The use and distribution terms for this software are covered by the
 *   Eclipse Public License 1.0 (http://opensource.org/licenses/eclipse-1.0.php)
 *   which can be found in the file epl-v10.html at the root of this distribution.
 *   By using this software in any fashion, you are agreeing to be bound by
 *   the terms of this license.
 *   You must not remove this notice, or any other, from this software.
 **/

// … beginning of the file omitted …

// the next line is the 190th in the file as of Clojure 1.9.0
static public Object ret1(Object ret, Object nil){
        return ret;
}

static public ISeq ret1(ISeq ret, Object nil){
        return ret;
}

// …
```

Given the above, the call to `drop` inside `nth` can be changed to

```
drop(n, ret1(lazySeq, lazySeq = null))
```

Here `lazySeq = null` is evaluated as an expression before control is transferred to `ret1`; the value is `null` and there is also the side effect of setting the `lazySeq` reference to `null`. The first argument to `ret1` will have been evaluated by this point, however, so `ret1` receives the reference to the sequence in its first argument and returns it as expected, and that value is then passed to `drop`.

Thus `drop` receives the original value held by the `lazySeq` local, but the local itself is cleared before control is transferred to `drop`.

Consequently `nth` no longer holds on to the head of the sequence.

Comment: The actual question – *where's the "leak"* – is fully addressed by Holger's answer, but I thought this would be useful as an extra piece of related information.

Comment: I implemented a `ret1()` method in my tests (e.g. https://github.com/Bill/java-garbage-test/blob/master/src/test/java/ClearingArgsGarbageTest.java#L71) and now they all scale (and pass!) without the need for the `-Xcomp` JVM option.

I still think it is infeasible to implement immutable, lazy, _scalable_ sequences in a Java _library_. The `ret1()` trick got us closer (than the `-Xcomp`) trick. But sequence handling code is still pretty contorted. I don't think it's feasible to write (and debug, and maintain) that sort of code by hand.