# function forwarding Stream parameter to another function retains reference

Tags: scala, memory-management, clojure, garbage-collection, sequence

I am able to write a Stream-processing function, `drop(n,s)`, that scales to very large streams. But when I write another function, `nth(n,s)`, that takes a stream `s` and forwards it to `drop(n,s)`, it seems that `nth()` is "holding on to the head" of the stream. This results in an `OutOfMemoryError` for large `n`.

Here's the code:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream.cons

object Streams {

  def iterate[A](start: A, f: A => A): Stream[A] =
    cons(start, iterate(f(start), f))

  def inc(n:Int) = n + 1

  def naturals() =
    iterate(1, inc)

  @tailrec def drop[T](n : Int, s : Stream[T]) : Stream[T] =
    if (n <= 0 || s.isEmpty) s
    else drop(n-1, s.tail)

  // @inline didn't seem to help
  def nth[T](n : Int, s : Stream[T]) =
    drop(n,s).head

  def N = 1e7.toInt

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(drop(N,naturals()).head) // works fine for large N
    println(nth(N, naturals())) // results in OutOfMemoryError for N set to 1e7.toInt and -Xmx10m
  }

}
```

My experience over on this Java question: [why does this Java method leak—and why does inlining it fix the leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169895/why-does-this-java-method-leak-and-why-does-inlining-it-fix-the-leak) leads me to believe that the Scala-generated code for `nth()` is not being aggressive enough in clearing `s` before calling `drop()`. The Clojure library trick (Java trick) (see that linked question) doesn't work here because all Scala function parameters are `val`s (not `var`s) so they can't be assigned (`null`).

How can I write a scalable `nth()` in terms of `drop()`?

Here is a related Scala compiler bug from 2009-2011 (`reduceLeft()` implemented in terms of `foldLeft()`): https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2239

I can't tell from that Scala bug ticket, how they fixed it. There was a suggestion in the ticket that the only way to fix it was to duplicate the `foldLeft()` code in `reduceLeft()`. I really hope that isn't the answer.

**Update**: Andrey Tyukin's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52209383/156550 fixes it. Now I have:

```
// have to call by name (s) here, otherwise we hold on to head!
def nth[T](n : Int, s : => Stream[T]) =
  drop(n,s).head
```

And `nth(n,s)` scales fine.

Comment: Had to add `-J-Xmx10m -J-Xms10m` to reproduce it, the `-Xmx10m` hint seemed like an approximation.

Comment: I am not sure how you expect it to work. If you did something like `val s = naturals;  val tenth = nth(10, s); val fifth = nth(5, s)`, what value would you expect `fifth` to have?

Comment: @Dima (with `val s = naturals()`) `fifth` would equal `6` but the point is not the _correctness_ of the `nth()` fn—the point is the _scalability_ of the `nth()` fn. The problem was that even without holding the head explicitly (as you did in your example), my initial implementation of `nth(n,s)` was holding on to `s` because of the call by _value_ semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick-&-dirty solution that takes just two extra characters:

```
def nth[T](n : Int, s: => Stream[T]) = drop(n,s).head
```

Here is what happens without the `=>`:

- When the stream `s` is passed as argument to `nth`, it is a reference to an already existing value, previously created by `naturals()`.
- Because of the `.head`, the `drop(n, s)` has to return the stream to the stack frame of `nth`, therefore the stackframe of `nth` cannot be discarded, and so `nth` holds on to the reference `s`.
- Because the reference to the parameter `s` is kept by the stack frame of `nth` while `drop` is working, all the dropped prefixes cannot actually be garbage-collected (this is because `Stream` guarantees that if you hold on to its head and iterate through it multiple times, it will return the same results).

Now, if you add `=>`, then the following happens:

- The stack frame of `nth` still cannot be discarded because of `.head`
- **But**: `nth` does not hold the reference to the head of the stream passed to `drop`. It only holds a reference to a *thunk* that produces the `Stream`.
- The thunk itself does not take up any significant amount of memory, and it does not hold any references to the head of the created stream, therefore, the prefix of the stream can be garbage-collected.

---

Additional note (Dima's test case):

Note that if the thunk itself simply returns a reference to an already existing `Stream`, then the behavior is still the same as without `=>`. For example, if your `inc` were defined as follows:

```
def inc(i: Int): Int = {
  println(System.currentTimeMillis())
  i + 1
}
```

then invoking

```
val s = naturals()
nth(10, s)
nth(5, s)
```

would print the current time only ten times (not 15).